# Display remote content - Joomla

Tags: json, spring, joomla, jqgrid, rss

I have a spring MVC app and a joomla "showcase web site".

How can I display data from spring MVC in my joomla showcase site?

My first attempt was to create a simple joomla module with inside jqgrid. But I discovered that many browser deny JSON cross domain and that this attempt is not good.

I also tried with an IFrame.. but I don't like this approach..

The current attempt is to export data from MVC app in RSS. I've installed an rss module in joomla and it works. But it's limited in search and sorting operation.

It would be great to find a way that permit to filter and sort data using some existent and open joomla module.

Does anyone have suggestion on proper export data tecnology and a related module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@mserioli
You should use the php curl, and in your module you make the request using the GET or POST method to retrieve data (json/xml) from your MVC app